# WPF. Splitters between GridViewColumnHeaders

Tags: wpf, gridview

Where `GridView`'s column header splitters are defined? I tried to use Snoop to find them, but I just can't localize template I need.`GridViewColumnHeader` does not define any splitters. The problem is that default ones are to thin and sometimes It is really hard to select them. Did anyone ever change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a poke around and found a thumb control is used for the splitting behaviour. Although it looks slim the Thumb is 18px wide.

You can change it by altering the template part named `PART_HeaderGripper` which is defined in the template for a [GridViewColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumnheader%28VS.85%29.aspx). A simple way to do this in blend is add a GridViewColumnHeader to your window right click and and edit a copy of the template. Then you can apply your edited template by setting:

```
<GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}">.
```

The thumbs properties are set in a style named `GridViewColumnHeaderGripper`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just changed rectangle width to 2 px (instead of 0.5!) in GridViewColumnHeaderGripper